# update values in dataframe

Tags: numpy

I have a dataframe in which the second column is an array. I have an another dataframe which has 2 columns, from which the value has to be updated in the first dataframe.

I already tried using update, explode, map, assign method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Account': ['A1','A2','A3']})

groups = np.array([['g1','g2'],['g3','g4'],['g1','g2','g3']])

df["Group"] = groups.tolist()

key_values = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1','2','3','4','5'],'Group': ['g1','g2','g3','g4','g5']})
keys = key_values.set_index('Key')['ID']

ag = Accounts_Group.explode('Group')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Setup***

```
m = key_values.set_index('Group')['ID']
```

---

***Option 1***
`explode` + `map`

```
f = df.explode('Group')

res = f['Group'].map(m).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

```
0       [1, 2]
1       [3, 4]
2    [1, 2, 3]
Name: Group, dtype: object
```

---

***Option 2***
List comprehension + `map`

```
res = [[*map(m.get, el)] for el in df['Group']]
```

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

To assign it back:

```
df.assign(Group=res)
```

```
  Account      Group
0      A1     [1, 2]
1      A2     [3, 4]
2      A3  [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Great solutions yours too, I have a question, the explode function is only on python 2.7?

Comment: @BillyBonaros it's only available in `pandas 0.25` and up.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly convert them to strings and replace them. Then you can convert them to list again from string using ast

```
import ast
df['keys']=df.astype(str).replace(to_replace=list(key_values['Group']),value=list(key_values['ID']),regex=True)['Group']
df['keys']=df['keys'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))

print(df)

  Account         Group       keys
0      A1      [g1, g2]     [1, 2]
1      A2      [g3, g4]     [3, 4]
2      A3  [g1, g2, g3]  [1, 2, 3]
```